# Can't Seem to call server methods in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I've been working with SignalR with MVC4 for a few weeks and have been successful for the most part when it comes to simple setups.  I've had no problems sending out messages to all clients from the server with one page setups and a hub.

The current project I'm working on, I'm trying to use groups, so after I start the client connection, I try to make a call to the server like so.

in my _Layout.cshtml

```
 var dashboardhub;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dashboardhub = $.connection.dashboardHub;

        dashboardhub.client.connect = function () { };
        window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start();
 });
```

in my Index.cshtml

```
window.hubReady.done(function () {
            dashboardhub.server.addGroup('@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString()');
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log('connection failed');
        });
```

In my DashboardHub class

```
public class DashboardHub : Hub {        

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public DashboardHub() {            

    }

    public void AddGroup(string group) {            
        this.Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);            
    }
}
```

When dashboardhub.server.addGroup is fired on the client side, I never see it hit the server method AddGroup.  This is obviously making it difficult to create groups.

It's very possible I'm missing something, but I'm not totally sure what that might be.  Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry for the pointless post.  There was something in the hub constructor that was throwing an exception, but it was very much not apparent.  Obviously it's not in the code I posted, but basically, I had added a PropertyChanged event handler on an object that was null in the constructor.  This basically broke the entire hub, which didn't allow server calls.

Comment: Answer your own question and mark it as answered.

Comment: I'll do that in a few hours when I'm allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the pointless post. There was something in the hub constructor that was throwing an exception, but it was very much not apparent. Obviously it's not in the code I posted, but basically, I had added a PropertyChanged event handler on an object that was null in the constructor. This basically broke the entire hub, which didn't allow server calls.